# Embedding JSON & JS into HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I am trying to embed my JS and JSON into my HTML form.

Any idea on how? and Where I should place my .js and .json?
My JSON is currently 1800 lines long, so I won't include. Working on an OS project. Just want my JS to trigger the JSON functionality when submitted. Is there an easy way to link both in the form?

My search bar code is located below.

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://google.com">
   <div class="inner-form">
      <div class="input-field first-wrap">
         <div class="svg-wrapper">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
               <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
            </svg>
         </div>
         <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Paste a domain here" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-field second-wrap">
         <button class="btn-search" action="https://www.google.com" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <span class="info">ex. JeepBeef.com</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, embed how? Can you post an example or better description on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You haven't included any JavaScript nor JSON in your example. Considering you haven't mentioned what the code is or what the code does, it is impossible to tell you how it *can* be integrated, let alone how you *want* to integrate it (which is also a subjective personal opinion).

Comment: My JSON is currently 1800 lines long, so I won't include. Working on an OS project. Just want my JS to trigger the JSON functionality when submitted. Is there an easy way to link both in the form? @ΔO'deltazero'

Comment: Did you mean that you want to do some work on submit? why not giving a minimalistic sample on want you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to trigger a function on `submit` event?

Comment: @Novy when submitted, the form will provide relevant details towards associated with that domain being searched. I have a JSON file specifying the details it would need to display, the Schema set, and the Javascript to pull in the JSON.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Yes.. I think. Something like that. See my comment above and let me know if that would still be relevent